# SQL Server: Extract the rows that come after a row containing specific text

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to extract ONLY the first row that come directly after the rows containing `type` = 'Email'?

Sample table:

```
id     type      details
1   Email   admin@sqlfiddle.com
2   1234    1234
3   Email   orange@hotmail.com
4   12345   12345
5   123456  123456
6   Email   cake@hotmail.com
7   1234567     1234567
8   12345678    12345678
9   123456789   123456789
10  Email   lala@gmail.com
11  01      01
12  Email   apple@yahoo.ca
13  012     012
14  Email   red@gmail.com
15  0123    0123
```

With Python and Pandas, I would write something like this...

```
indexes = table[table['type']=='Email'].index + 1
table = table.ix[indexes]
```

Where the output would be...

```
2   1234    1234
4   12345   12345
7   1234567     1234567
11  01  01
13  012     012
15  0123    0123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  *

from   (select  *
               ,lag (type) over (order by id) as prev_type

        from    t
        ) t

where   prev_type = 'Email'
```

Comment: what do you mean by "lag"... is there keyword or anything?

Comment: lag is a function you can use to get the next value

Comment: Value from a **previous** row

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz :- dude you are awesome...you teach me one lesson today..

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server Query like this

```
select * from table where id in (Select id+1 from Table where type='Email')
```

Comment: I just want the first rows that comes directly after type = Email

Comment: you are looking for this..?

Comment: Getting warmer, but for all entries with type = 'Email'. It should resemble the output I have in my original post.

Comment: I hope this will help you??

Comment: You are assuming that id has no gaps

Comment: Thanks Darshak - this works if an ID is given. But what if no such column exists or the ID is a string like "AB7007"?

Comment: ... and it is going to fail due to equality condition with a query that returns multiple values

Comment: @RileyHun :- i guess id is your primary key field of the table..right??

Comment: Yes - that's correct, so I would just ignore it altogether

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz :- i dont understand your query..its give correct output what it required?

Comment: It works okay for me except it creates an additional column that I'd rather not have

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically wanting just the first record after the email row you could be a bit more selective like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID+1 FROM Table where type='Email')
```

Comment: Just noticed your field is called ID, sorry, edited!

Comment: Thanks Conrad! This works great if an ID is given, but what if one isn't given. Is there a generalized way to do this?

Comment: You are assuming that id has no gaps

Comment: Well the real data has ID that's a string like "AB7897".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work even if id has gaps. It uses window functions.

```
---Sample data
WITH data([id], [type] , [details]) AS
(
    SELECT 1,'Email','admin@sqlfiddle.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'1234', '1234' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'Email','orange@hotmail.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'12345','12345' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'123456',  '123456' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'Email','cake@hotmail.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,'1234567',  '1234567' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,'12345678', '12345678' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,'123456789','123456789' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,  'Email','lala@gmail.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11,  '01','01' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12,  'Email','apple@yahoo.ca' UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 , '012',  '012' UNION ALL
    SELECT 14  ,'Email','red@gmail.com' UNION ALL
    SELECT 15  ,'0123', '0123'
),
---temporary table to hold row numbers
tbl([Row_Num], [id], [type]) AS
(
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [id])) AS [Row_Num] ,[id],[type] FROM data 
)

---actual query using both tables
SELECT 
    d.[id], 
    d.[type], 
    d.[details] 
FROM [data] d 

INNER JOIN

[tbl] t

ON d.[id] = t.[id] 

WHERE t.[Row_Num] IN (SELECT Row_Num + 1 FROM tbl WHERE [type] = 'Email')
```